# How to remap couple of keys on a keyboard on Windows 7

Tags: keyboard, key, remap

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 64-bit.

I want to make the left "Caps Lock" key to act as "Ctrl+F" when clicked, and the left "Shift" key to act as "Enter" when clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This link worked for me

[Keymapper](https://code.google.com/p/keymapper/downloads/detail?name=KeyMapper.msi)

https://code.google.com/p/keymapper/downloads/detail?name=KeyMapper.msi